# A pokemon's CP reduces after being caught?

Tags: pokemon-go

The only guess I have for this is my level...

When I discovered my first Beedrill, it was CP 172, and it broke out of 4-5 pokeballs before capture.  After registering in Pokedex, then added to my collection, it was CP 56, a loss of 116 CP points.

This is the only time I've noticed a CP # different to what it was when entered into my collection.

Answer (score 1):

The CP (and IVs for that matter) do not change from the time you encounter a Pokemon to the time that you capture it.

I have not personally encountered this, but I suspect it is a bug.

Comment: This occurred during my first few days of playing the game in early July, and I was taking constant screenshots of everything, and have a series screen captures that demonstrate the above as described. 

Yes I agree, it may (must likely) have been a bug.

Comment: Has it happened again since then?

Comment: Not once! :) The app seems much more stable, fortunately, as the updates come out.  But I still see people posting fresh screens from android apps of micro-sized pokemon, and other odd things.

Comment: There are definitely still odd things here and there, but it's good to know this particular bug has been fixed.